# React Native - Upload Array of Images to Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload an array of image URI's from application cache to firebase storage.

Once the images have been uploaded to firebase storage, the a callback to get the downloadURL for the file is called, and a document is created in firestore for the record. This record contains the first image. If multiple images have been taken, on the second photo, the firestore document is updated and new images are appended into image object (array).

Running this code has had 3 outcomes:

1. 1 image uploaded
2. all images uploaded
3. no images loaded, application crashes

Any idea what I am doing incorrectly?

```
//Uploads Images
const uploadImages = async () => {
    for (const image of images) {
        const response = await fetch(image);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(REDACTED + ".jpg");
        const task = storageRef.put(blob);
        setLoading(true);
        task.on('state_changed', taskSnapshot => {
            console.log(`${taskSnapshot.bytesTransferred} transferred out of ${taskSnapshot.totalBytes}`);
        });
        await task.then(() => {
            const dlURL = storageRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
                console.log("Download URL: ", url);
                updateFirestore(url);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log("Error getting download url: ", error)
            });
            setLoading(false);
            console.log("Image Successfully Uploaded");
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error Uploading Images: ", error);
            setLoading(false);
        });
    }
}
//Updates table in Firestore
const updateFirestore = (dlURL) => {
    console.log("PIC CODE: ", picCode);
    if (picCode === 0) {
        console.log("Creating Document...");
        //Create
        dbRef.add({
            ...
            images: [
                dlURL
            ]
        }).then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
            setDocID(result.id);
            //picCode++;
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error)
        });
    } else {
        console.log("Updating Document...", docID);
        //Update
        dbRef.doc(docID).update({
            images: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(dlURL)
        }).then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
            //picCode++;
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error)
        });
    }
    picCode++;
};
```

```
Log Output:
Image:  file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/483FC505-968F-4850-87E3-8CC6DD824A53/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540arcade336%252Fempireportal/Camera/A68C3715-DD20-41C3-9711-E1C80E7B31A3.jpg
0 transferred out of 3777563
262144 transferred out of 3777563
786432 transferred out of 3777563
1835008 transferred out of 3777563
```

Comment: I don't immediately see what's going on, so you might want include the output of the log statements in your question too. Especially the `console.log("PIC CODE: ", picCode);` looks like it might be helpful.

Comment: Why not rethink your problem and spawn a whole bunch of `UploadProgress` elements under some `UploadProgressGroup` element, one for each image, responsible for showing the state of each upload and adding it to Cloud Firestore when complete. If one in the set fails, show a retry button to reattempt just that one rather than all of them again.

Comment: Based on your current code though, you currently have many floating promises (I.e. they don't return/await to their caller) and an `await` inside a for loop. You should add names to each `console.error` to help tracking down what is what (i.e. `console.error('in update Firestore for pic 0:', error)`. Then check your logs again and post anything relevant here.